# 'haslayer' function not working in scapy-python

Tags: python, scapy

I'm trying to write a simple code that detect IP source address for ICMP packet in `scapy`, the problem is `haslayer` function looks not returning anything.

```
from scapy.all import *

while 1:

    pkt = sniff ( iface="eth0" , count = 1 )
    pkt.summary()

    try:
        if pkt.haslayer(IP):
            ipsrc =pkt.getlayer(IP).src
            print ipsrc

    except:
        pass
```

the result is

```
Ether / IP / ICMP 10.0.2.15 > 10.0.2.11 echo-request 0 / Raw
Ether / IP / ICMP 10.0.2.15 > 10.0.2.11 echo-request 0 / Raw
Ether / IP / ICMP 10.0.2.15 > 10.0.2.11 echo-request 0 / Raw
```

So I'm not able to catch the IP source address for the ICMP request
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your generic `except` masks any errors that your code might encounter. Change `pass` to `raise` and remove any specific errors. E.g. the first I encountered with your code was:

```
socket.error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

and after running as `root` I got:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'haslayer'
```

and that made me change the code to something that worked (running as `root`):

```
from scapy.all import *

while 1:

    pktl = sniff ( iface="eth0" , count = 1 )
    pktl.summary()

    for pkt in pktl:
        try:
            if pkt.haslayer(IP):
                ipsrc =pkt.getlayer(IP).src
                print ipsrc
        except:
            raise
```

So you probably better of removing the try - except altogether

Comment: worked like a charm , many thanks . but it's not documented that i need to do a loop for alive capturing .

Comment: I guessed it from the `list` in the AttributeError and the count argument to `sniff` that the latter could give more than one value back. But the important thing is not to throw away useful errors with a non-specific `except:`

Answer (score 1):

@Hussam - You don't need a loop but if you use the syntax pkt = sniff() then it's returning an array. Another way to write it would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from scapy.all import *

pkt = sniff(count=1, filter="ip")

if pkt[0].haslayer(IP):
    print pkt[0][IP].src
```

You can also do this with a function passed to sniff() where every packet is passed to the function as a packet instead of an array. An example would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from scapy.all import *

def print_ip_src(pkt):
    if pkt.haslayer(IP):
        print pkt[IP].src

sniff(prn=print_ip_src, filter="ip")
```

Notice there's no loop or assigning a variable from the function. This will run indefinitely and every packet will be sent to the print_ip_src() function I included.

P.S.: I used a BPF filter to only capture IP packets however you should still include the haslayer() function, regardless, as a safety measure.